# Ansible: do not run shell command if a file exists

Tags: ansible

I would like to do the following in an Ansible playbook:

```
- name: "Generate variant html report"
  shell: "<my command>"
  with_items: "{{ variants | default([]) }}"
  when: ({{ folderReports }}/{{ item }}).exists == False
```

Inside the `when`, I need a way to create the file path, and determine if it exists or not. I tried to use the "(" ")" to surround my first expression, but it doesn't seem to be working:

> 2016-10-13 16:22:48,130 p=94292 u=sautomation |  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '({{ folderReports }}/{{ item }}).exists == True' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {% if (/opt/diff-test1.diff).exists == True %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/opt/ansible/roles/stats/tasks/main.yml': line 45, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"Generate report\"\n  ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent a task from executing if a specified file already exists, use `creates` parameter of the [`shell`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) module:

```
- name: "Generate variant html report"
  shell: "<my command>"
  args:
    creates: "{{ folderReports }}/{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ variants | default([]) }}"
```

---

You get an error because `.exists`, in your conditional, checks if a variable (fact) exist, not a file on the target node.

Comment: I don't understand what you say now. It is exactly what you specified in the question: task has to run if the file does not exist (`.exist == False`). It is the same as "when the file **exists**, this step **will not** be run."

Comment: Sorry, you are totally right. In another part of the playbook, I need to perform an action only if the file exists. Is there a way to do that as well?

Comment: In two steps: first check if the file exists using [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) module by specifying the path to the file you want to check, then execute the task with conditional based on the returned value of `matched`.

Comment: If I understand correctly your suggestion, this wouldn't work if I need to do the condition inside a "with_items" like in my previous example right?

Comment: First you use `find` to look for files matching your `variants`, then you use `find`'s output `files` in the condition for the task to run. Please see the doc page I linked in the comment above. This is a different problem and it's hard to deal in comments. I think you should try to implement it and if you encounter a problem, create a separate question with code example and the results.